# facebook publish to wall as page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am developing a facebook application.

In my application I'd like to give page administrators the ability to publish to their page's wall, not as a user, but rather as they page itself.

Can this be done? If so how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apperently this possible when prompting user with the "manage_pages" permission. Then it is possible to query the page's access token, and perform the operation in the page's name. 
You can check this documentation down here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

And here's a small code sample, of how it might look using the facebook c# sdk:

```
            dynamic pagesInfo = FacebookApp.Api("/me/accounts");
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string pageAccessToken = null;
            foreach(IDictionary<string,object> page in serializer.DeserializeObject(pagesInfo.data.ToString()))
            {
                long pageId = long.Parse(page["id"].ToString());
                if (pageId == localBusiness.FanPageId)
                {
                    pageAccessToken = page["access_token"].ToString();
                }
            }
            if (pageAccessToken == null)
                return;

        var pageFbApp = new FacebookApp(pageAccessToken);
        // post as application
        Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>()
                                                {
                                                    {"from", 
                                                    new Dictionary<string,object>()
                                                    {
                                                        {"id" , localBusiness.FanPageId},
                                                        {"name" , localBusiness.Name}
                                                    }},
                                                    {"description", description},
                                                    {"link", pageUrl },
                                                    {"name", name  },
                                                    {"picture" , imageUrl }
                                                };

        dynamic result = pageFbApp.Post(localBusiness.FanPageId + "/feed", parameters);
```